# How Eratosthenes measured the Earth's circumference

Tags: circles, math-history

When Eratosthenes measured the Earth's circumference, he provided $250,000$ stadia as its measure equal to about $25,000 $miles. Since the radian is a dimensionless number, the radian couldn't have been part of his original calculations. That being so, can the radian ~ $\frac{180}{\pi}$be considered relevant to the Earth's circumference or any other circumference requiring a unit of measure?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption “Since the radian is a dimensionless number, the radian couldn't have been part of his original calculations” is wrong. Indeed, Eratosthenes did not use radians. He could no possible have done it, since they would be invented many centuries after his time.  But he did use another dimensionless number in is computations: he used the fact that the measure of the angle Alexandria—center of the Earth—Syenne is $\frac1{50}$ of a full angle. And this $\frac1{50}$ is a dimensionless number.

Comment: We agree then that Eratosthenes didn't use radians; the radian is not essential when measuring a circle's circumference. Would that be a fair statement? To help determine whether the radian is indeed essential, I submit the haversine formula for measuring distances on Earth: 2 * radius (in a unit of measure) * atan2(√a, √1-a). Considering that the haversine formula, which has the distinction of being accurate, omits the radian can we conclusively omit the radian from measuring an arbitrary circumference and determine that it's unnecessary?

Comment: No specific unit of measure is essential for such a measurement.

Comment: The haversine formula uses latitude and longitude to determine distance. Latitude and longitude are based on degrees. For instance: 60° East, 90° North. Degrees are dimensionless but distance is not. Mathematics is the study of distance. Ultimately, latitude and longitude are defined by a unit of measure whether that is the Metric system or the US Customary system. Eratosthenes, an ancient Greek, used the stadia as his unit of measure. When is a unit of measure necessary and when is not? Are we to understand that Eratosthenes was in error for using the stadia as his unit of measure?

Comment: Eratosthenes was *not* in error. Mathematics is *not* the study of distance. And using some unit of measure is often necessary. What is not necessary in general is to use a *specific* unit of measure, such as the radian or the kilometer.

Comment: We concur that Eratosthenes was not in error for not using the radian when he measured the Earth's circumference. Therefore, we can conclude that the radian is not essential when measuring an arbitrary circumference. Otherwise, Eratosthenes, an ancient Greek, would be in error for using a unit of measure appropriate to his era. What all of this means is that specific units of measure (or lack thereof) are optional. Take it or leave it. The radian is not a must. Are we in agreement?

Comment: Sure, since that is what I have been saying all along.

Comment: We agree that the radian is optional. An arbitrary circumference, including the unit circle circumference, is not required to be measured according to 180/π which is the representation of the radian. Hence, π radians and π itself is optional. The circle is not necessarily defined by π and can be defined in other ways if so desired. The system is saying, "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" Thank you for the discussion. I appreciate your feedback.